# Find every [ 1st,2nd,3rd ] day of week using carbon For next 15 day

Tags: php, laravel

Find every [ 1st,2nd,3rd ]day's  date of week using `carbon` For next 15 day.

Is there any method similar to `momentjs` in Carbon

Below showcase same example using `momentjs`.

```
momementObj.recur().every([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).daysOfWeek();
```

Comment: day means you want to return date , am i right ?

Comment: Yes i mean date

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this part of the documentation: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-week

So for example for one week:

```
$en = CarbonImmutable::parse('2017-02-05');
var_dump($en->week(1)->format('Y-m-d H:i')); //string(16) "2017-01-01 00:00"
var_dump($en->week(6)->format('Y-m-d H:i')); //string(16) "2017-01-06 00:00"
```

check the documentation its clear, please if you need futher clarification just comment.

Week days go from 0 to 6

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Carbon has this out-of-the-box but with great tools like this you can use `CarbonPeriod` to achieve this, see: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period. You can end up with something like this:

```
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
...

function dateInRange(array $days_of_week = [1,2,3], int $in_days = 15)
{
    $days = CarbonPeriod::create(Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->addDay($in_days));

    $result = [];
    /**
     * @var Carbon $carbon
     */
    foreach ($days as $carbon) { //This is an iterator
        if (in_array($carbon->dayOfWeek, $days_of_week, true)) {
            $result[] = $carbon->format('Y-m-d D');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

- `$days` gives you Carbon period which is an `Iterator`
- Allows you to iterate over each 'period' between the two dates
- You then do the check when iterating them while populating your initial array
- You can simply return `$carbon` as a Carbon instance inside the loop instead of formatting it (I just did it to demo that it returns the day of the week)

> PS: By default, 0 is Sunday in Carbon, 1 is Monday...and so on.